# ping удаленного компьютера на Lua

Tags: ip, lua, ping

Интересует такой вопрос. Как пропинговать с портом на Lua удаленный компьютер/сервер в сети если неизвестно на какой ОС будет использоваться скрипт и очень критично быстродействие пинга?
Пробовал эту команду `io.popen()` но проблема в том что если комп не доступен, скрипт может зависнуть с блокировкой потока на некоторое время, что в моем случае недопустимо.
Нужно простое и быстрое решение которое пинговало на Lua удаленный комп/серв и если он не ответил сразу то не ждать его, а сразу обрывать связь и возвращать отказ. Пинг возможен как по IP адресу так и по имени с портом например - `google.com 80 (port)`.
Никак не могу найти в интернете решение этой задачи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно рассмотреть попытку открытия порта через сокет, если доступен порт, то соединение состоится, таймаут сами укажите:

```
require("socket")   

local host = "87.250.250.242"

local conn = socket.tcp()
conn:settimeout(1, 't') -- таймаут 1 сек
local res = conn:connect(host, 80)
if res then     print("Connected")  
else    print('Error connect')
end

conn:close()

-- Name to IP
local name = socket.dns.tohostname(host)
print (host, name)
-- IP to Name
local adr = "google.com"
local info = socket.dns.toip(adr)
print(adr,info)
```

результат:

```
Connected
87.250.250.242  ya.ru
google.com  142.251.1.138
```

Comment: Отличный ответ. Будь еще функция определения адреса по имени, было бы вообще шикарно

Comment: @Venen добавил dns.toip()

Answer (score 0):

Для виндовс всё сложно, но можно попробовать cygwin.

Для посиксов (линукс, мак, бсд, cygwin)

```
#!/usr/bin/env lua

local M = require 'posix.sys.socket'


if M.SOCK_RAW and M.SO_BINDTODEVICE then
   -- Open raw socket

   local fd, err = M.socket(M.AF_INET, M.SOCK_RAW, M.IPPROTO_ICMP)
   assert(fd, err)

   -- Optionally, bind to specific device

   local ok, err = M.setsockopt(fd, M.SOL_SOCKET, M.SO_BINDTODEVICE, 'wlan0')
   assert(ok, err)

   -- Create raw ICMP echo (ping) message

   local data = string.char(0x08, 0x00, 0x89, 0x98, 0x6e, 0x63, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00)

   -- Send message

   local ok, err = M.sendto(fd, data, {family=M.AF_INET, addr='8.8.8.8', port=0})
   assert(ok, err)

   -- Read reply

   local data, sa = M.recvfrom(fd, 1024)
   assert(data, sa)

   if data then
      print('Received ICMP message from ' .. sa.addr)
   end
end
```

Для определения имени добавь

```
r, err = M.getaddrinfo('www.lua.org', 'http', {family=M.AF_INET, socktype=M.SOCK_STREAM})
r[1].addr
```

Для установки таймаутов нужно добавить в этот код select и неблокирующие сокеты.

https://luaposix.github.io/luaposix/examples/ping.lua.html
https://luaposix.github.io/luaposix/examples/socket.lua.html

Пинг работает без порта, но если мы говорим о syn scan атаке, то это уже другой код.

Можно в этом случае обойтись более простой `luasocket` но будет блокировка до таймаута.

Comment: 'posix.sys.socket' есть на luarocks?

Comment: @Venen `luarocks install luaposix`

Comment: я правильно понимаю что универсального решения задачи тут нет?

Comment: на виндовс я не умею. универсальное если и есть, то там внутри `if ( windows ) winping() else posixping()`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ